# HAML inline javascript syntax highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim, haml, syntax-highlighting, macvim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have added some javascript code in my haml %script tag. But I noticed that syntax highlighting doesn't work for the javascript code inside the tag. Is there any good plug-in that can handle this?
btw I use mac vim.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:set ft=haml.javascript`.